# How can I console "Sucess" present on $.ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I show "success" up on Console screen? In a nutshell, I want to show on Console the erros that I forced to happen in a register formulary.

```
function getRoot() {
    var root = "http://" + document.location.hostname + "/login_AMUBA/";
    return root;
}

$("#formCadastro").on("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var dados = $(this).serialize();

    function response() {
        return $.ajax({
            url: getRoot() + 'controllers/controllerCadastro',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: dados,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    }
    if (response) {
        console.log(success);<--Here
    }

});
```

Finally, the final function (on a php file) should show the error(errors) on console screen, but only "else" works (when it is not commented)

```
public function validateFinalCad($arrVar)
    {
        if (count($this->getErro()) > 0) {
            $arrResponse = [
                "retorno" => "erro",
                "erros" => $this->getErro()
            ];
        } else {
            /*$this->cadastro->insertCad($arrVar);*/
        }
        return json_encode($arrResponse);
    }
```

Comment: This lines `success: function (response) { console.log(response); }` should do that

Comment: Probably `if (response) {` is not calling the function without a `()` like `if (response()) {`

Comment: But if you want something back from the function think SCOPE, return it

Comment: You also would need to quote `success` otherwise it will try to find a variable with that name `console.log('success')`

Comment: Actually, the problem is to show the success. But it isn't all...public function validateFinalCad($arrVar)
    `{
        if (count($this->getErro()) > 0) {
            $arrResponse = [
                "retorno" => "erro",
                "erros" => $this->getErro()
            ];
        } else {
            /*$this->cadastro->insertCad($arrVar);*/
        }
        return json_encode($arrResponse);
    }` 

this code work 50%, because `if` does not work, only `else` (when it is not commented)

Comment: I will add this, wait

Comment: If you want to see what errors you likly need to hook either the `error` callback or a `complete` callback.  What is the response code from the server for this situation, cause it should be an error code?

Comment: I am working with a formulary. So I'm validating all spaces in this form. But, when something is wrong, it must show the error on console, as expected from the codes

Comment: The following text should appear, for example:
erros : [
(0) "Invalid email!"];